# How to decompile Blackberry application (.cod)

Tags: blackberry

Is there any .cod (Blackberry application) decompiler available?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Coddec](http://drbolsen.wordpress.com/) claims to be a decompiler.